# Using GetProcAddress with offset syntax

Tags: assembly, array, offset, process, call

I have the following line (I use IDA PRO) :

```
   ...
   push (offset aPstorec_dllwne+0Ch)      ; lpProcName
   push esi                               ; hModule
   call GetProcAddress_0
   ...
```

When I click on **(offset aPstorec_dllwne+0Ch)** I use:

```
   seg001:004012F0 ; char aPstorec_dllwne[] 
                   aPstorec_dllwne db 'pstorec.dll, 0 , 'WNetEnumCachedPasswords', 
                   0 , 'MPR.DLL' , 0 , 'SeDebugPrivilege', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
```

So my question is: 
How should I read it to get the info which process is meant? I know that each field of an array is 4 byte and the **db** at the beginning indicates that.
But when I count from zero, I come to the 0 after WNetEnumCachedPasswords. It is wrong, right?

best regards

Comment: `GetProcAddress` is *procedure* address, not process. And `db` is *data byte*. So you have to count 12 bytes from the start, which is just at the beginning of `WNetEnumCachedPasswords`. So, the call is getting the address of the `WNetEnumCachedPasswords` procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run across an API call that you're unfamiliar with, check the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx). Parameter 2 is "The function or variable name, or the function's ordinal value." Looking at your offset only one of those things is a function name, WNetEnumCachedPasswords.

You can verify this as the comment in your post said, by counting 12 (0xc) bytes from aPstorec_dllwne. db stands for databyte and you can also see that "char aPstorec_dllwne[]" designates a character array, also 1 byte per element.